# Looping & Nesting Promises

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, promise, request-promise

I am using [Request-Promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to scrape some website data, essentially I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Create An Empty Array
2. Login
3. Get some info from one page and push objects into the array
4. Get some info from another page and push objects into the array
5. For each now object in the array, I need to:

   - Go to the URL stored within that object **{link: "some url", items: []}**
   - loop through all the items found within that link, and push this to the items array within the iterated object as such: **{link: "some url", items: [{item},{item}]}**.
6. Access the completed **orderArray**, which should spit out something like this:

> ```
> {link: "some url", items: [{item},{item}]},
> {link: "some url", items: [{item},{item}]},
> {link: "some url", items: [{item},{item}]}
> ```

**Step 6** is where I'm running into issues, I don't know how to do this without nesting the promise inside a for loop as per my code below which then starts getting nasty. Can I be pointed in the right direction here?

Here is my current code:

> ```
>     let orderArray = [];
>
>     rp.post(login)
>
>     .then(function(res1){
>
>         // Login & Set Cookies
>         cookieJar = res1.headers['set-cookie'];
>
>         return rp(getOpenOrders);
>
>     })
>
>     .then(function($){
>
>         // Get Some Info from getOpenOrders
>
>         orderArray.push({info});
>
>         return rp(getShippedOrders);
>
>     })
>
>     .then(function($){
>
>         // Get Some Info from getShippedOrders
>
>         orderArray.push({info});
>
>         return orderArray;
>
>     })
>
>     .then(function($){
>
>         // Loop through each object in the orderArray
>         for (i = 0,; i < orderArray.length; i++){
>
>             rp(orderArray[I].link)
>
>             .then(function($){
>
>             //Get length of items on page
>             let itemsOnPage = $('tbody tr').length;
>
>             //Get some more details for each object
>             for (j = 0,; j < items.length; j++) {
>                     let moreinfo = {…};
>                     orderArray.items.push(moreinfo);
>             }
>
>           }
>         }
>
>         return orderArray;
>
>     })
>
>     .then(function($){
>
>         // Log finished Array
>         console.log(orderArray);
>
>     })
>
>     .catch(function(err){
>         console.log(err);
>     })
>
>     };
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way is using `async/await`. That code won't run in parallel though (Unless we await `Promise.all`)

```
.then(async() => {

    // Loop through each object in the orderArray
    for(let i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {

        // Some may argue no await inside loop...
        // We wait for rp to resolve, it looks like
        // synchronous code so it's easy to understand
        const $ = await rp(orderArray[i].link);

        let items = $('tbody tr');

        for(const item of items) {
            let moreinfo = {};
            orderArray[i].items.push(moreinfo);
        }

    }

    return orderArray;
})
```

You can also use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to send all requests in parallel and handle the results when they all finish.

```
.then(() => {

    // Loop through each object in the orderArray

    const requests = [];

    for(const order of orderArray) {
        // Push each promise
        requests.push(
            rp(order.link)
        );
    }

    // This will resolve when every request finishes
    // If one fails, it will reject, going to `.catch`
    return Promise.all(requests); 
})
.then(results => {

    // Results is an array containing each individual request result.

    results.forEach(($, i) => {

        //Get length of items on page
        let items = $('tbody tr');

        //Get some more details for each object
        for(const item of items) {
            let moreinfo = {};
            orderArray[i].items.push(moreinfo);
        }

    })

    return orderArray;

});
```

I assume `rp` resolves a cheerio object, if it doesn't please let me know.

I can't test it because I don't have your full code, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a solution, both solutions worked like a beauty. In my instance I will move forward with the first method **(async/await)** as the **Promise.all** seemed to spit out 404 Errors from the particular site I'm scraping which the **async/await** did not cause (I'm assuming to fix this I'll probably need to .catch the URI that error'd and make it try again). 

Again - Thank you very much, I was on the edge of giving up!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Yeah the Promise.all is a fail fast function, so error handling is a pain. I usually use a wrapper that won't reject. But I would go with async await unless you need to go parallel by all means